# Facebook app - Paypal transaction within facebook?

Tags: iframe, paypal, facebook, paypal-ipn

Is it possible and if so how to do an IPN transaction within a facebook application?

I found you can not launch an IPN transaction within an iframe. I will be using facebook's iframe option for my application, so I need to figure out a way for the users to pay.

I guess it would be possible to launch a pop up with the transaction in there... but then there is the risk of pop up blockers etc.

How do developers normally receive payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to do simple micropayments (such as for virtual currency in a facebook app game) you may want to consider a 3rd party API such as SocialGold (http://www.jambool.com/)

SocialGold supports an iframe option by using a signature passing method and handles a wide variety of payment types, including PayPal.

If you want to avoid the risk of a popup blocker, consider instead using the iframe within an inline dialog within your application. There are many dialog handlers, but I recommend one that relies on JQuery myself:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/